# Cannot install latest version of PIL in Centos 5.8

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I cannot install PIL on my Centos 5.8 x64.
  I tried to install it using pip install PIL command. But it encounters a gcc error.
  Please see below error snippet:

```
_imagingft.c:475: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token

_imagingft.c:502: error: old-style parameter declarations in prototyped function definition

/usr/include/freetype2/freetype/freetype.h:1574: error: parameter name omitted

_imagingft.c:502: error: expected ‘{’ at end of input

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /usr/local/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/acresearch/downloads/py-modules/PIL/build/PIL/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-tHfjOz-record/install-record.txt failed with error code 1 in /home/acresearch/downloads/py-modules/PIL/build/PIL
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

I already checked if python-devel, libjpg and libpng are already installed (mentioned as possible resolution on some links I've read) and yes,they are installed. However, error still occurs.

Any ideas on how to resolve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: And what version of gcc you have?

Comment: Installing the `python-dev` package may fix this. Also, you can install PIL via yum: `yum install python-imaging`.

Comment: `python-devel` on CentOS, `python-dev` on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

hello I had the same problem is solved by first installing this

```
yum install gcc
```

now you can install PIL with

```
pip install PIL
```